# tmux does not trigger when placed in rc.local

Tags: bash, tmux

I want to start a [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) on boot on a raspberry pi - 2. I have written a `session.sh` file and I have places it in `~/bin/` file which is in the home directory. This `~/bin/` is also included in the `$PATH` and hence It can be triggered.

The Bash file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mySession(){
     tmux new-session -d -s SessionName
     tmux new-window -d -n 'windowName' "~/bin/myPythonScript.py"
}
mySession

exit 0
```

I have given *execution* rights to all scripts including the above mentioned bash script too using `chmod +x session.sh`

In the **rc.local** I refer to trigger this file as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
scriptSession(){
        echo "starting the tmux session"
        ~/bin/session.sh &
}

scriptSession
exit 0
```

I have tried rebooting my Pi many times but the session never gets triggered.

when I execute `sudo tmux ls`, it just shows `error Connecting to Server`

however when I do `sudo /etc/rc.local` or `sudo ~/bin/session.sh` the session starts! I do not want this to happen since I want automatic start on boot not  a user triggered session

Any Idea what could be the problem?

### Edit

I also tried collecting a fail log in a bash subshell using thing the following in the **rc.local** file:

```
(scriptSession)&>>/var/log/myLog.txt
```

but upon `cat /var/log/myLog.txt` nothing shows up and the script still fails

Comment: I have just noticed: in your `rc.local` there is `scriptSession` function defined but never run. Yet you wrote "when I do `sudo /etc/rc.local` (...) the session starts". Does it really?

Comment: Hi , I actually do call the function ! there is a typo ! will fix it. but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most optimized solution to troubleshoot any detached script using **tmux** will require you to use the following option within your triggering script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script is called "sess"

tmux new-session -d -s sess1

# this statement is a life-saver for tmux detached sessions
tmux set-option -t sess1 remain-on-exit on

# In my case running the script in a new window worked
tmux new-window -d -n 'nameofWindow' -t sess1:1 'sudo /home/pi/bin/script.py'

exit 0
```

Now the following script was called from the `rc.local` and the Pi was rebooted. Eventually on reboot when you attach the session using `sudo tmux a` Once gets a tmux session with **2 windows**

1. Initial one is just an empty session triggered due to `tmux new-session -d -s sess1`
2. and the another one from the `tmux new-window` command which can be opened using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> since it was mentioned as `sess1:1` (*note:* Hot keys may vary for user, the default tmux hotkey (bindkeys) are <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)

### Inference

If the script ends with an error, the Window will show you where the error was in my case errors in my Python script and at the Bottom it will show **Pane is Dead**. Hence due to errors in the script the **tmux** session was exited without giving any relevant log(feedback) hence no output was logged in the above mentioned `/tmp/tmux.log`

Hence it is always recommended using the `set-remain-on-exit on` when running scripts with tmux in case if there are faults in the the script in detached mode

Comment: I think that's a nice idea, but alas - it did not work for me, and no session is visible when I log in. Using Kamil's recommendation to use abs paths also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think `rc.local` environment during startup isn't rich. If it knows any `$PATH` and `$HOME` (shell expands `~` to `$HOME`) they are not your (regular user's) variables; I think they may be unset. Furthermore the script will inherit this limited environment.

However when you do `sudo /etc/rc.local` or `sudo ~/bin/session.sh` the command inherits *your* environment and all works.

To fix it use full path instead of `~/`. Use full path to `tmux` also.

Comment: alright you mean `/usr/bin/tmux` ?

Comment: @Shan-Desai If that's where your `tmux` executable is – then yes.

Comment: Alright will have a try and get back to you thanks @Kamil

Comment: this still isn't working? any more hints?

Comment: finally figured out the problem @Kamil